# List of segments returned using google analytics API does not match with GA account

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to get list of segments from my GA account using [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/segments/list). However, there are some segments which I have created in GA, but I do not get them from the API.

Any reason as to why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure your authenticating in with the user that created them?   Can you post some code?

Comment: I am authenticating with the correct user. To avoid any code ambiguities, I used [oauthplayground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) but this too did not return the segment I was looking for.

Comment: Maybe you can try to recreate them as dynamical segment, just to see if there is some combination of conditions that is not supported in the API ?

Comment: Has your account been upgraded to Unified Segments? If so, this caused havoc for our segments when we were pulling them through API.

Comment: oauthplayground is working fine for me.  Something else must be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [new segmentation features](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2013/07/re-imagining-segmentation-in-analytics.html) were added this past July, and they are not currently supported in the API.

So if you segment on users using the new segments UI in the Web Interface, the segments won't show up when listing in the Management API, and they won't work with the Core Reporting API. However, session/visitor segments with conditions continue to work. This is why you're seeing this behavior...until the API has full support for this.

You can review the Management API changelog, [Release 2013-07-15](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/changelog) for exact details on this.

You should subscribe to the changelog so you'll be notified if support is added.

Comment: This is correct - I tested it.  It explains why some users are not able to see new segments they have created when they use our reporting tool:  [Megalytic](http://megalytic.com).  If anybody finds a workaround, or learns when the management api will be updated, we'd appreciate hearing about it.  I put in a [bug fix request](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=415) - please vote for it.